# pandas check null in data frame except one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `data frame` and I want do a `null check` and store the `null value rows` in separate data frame. But, one constrain is, I don't want to do null check for one particular column. How can I achieve this?

For example, In below Data Frame,

```
   Name  Age  Class
0   tom   10      NaN
1  nick   15     10
2  juli   14      9
```

If I apply, `df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]`, It gives me

```
   Name  Age  Class
0  tom   10    NaN
```

But, I want don't want to do null check for `Class` column and I'm expecting empty data frame for this case. I have searched in SO but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
cols_to_excl = ['Class']

df.loc[df[df.columns ^ cols_to_excl].isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

In essence: `df.columns ^ cols_to_excl` will return all columns, besides all the columns from the list `cols_to_excl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
df[df.iloc[:, :2].isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

This can work if you know that your function will only work on this dataframe otherwise you can try generalized approach as stated by @Grzegorz Skibinski

Answer (score 0):

xor operation will be deprecated in newer versions. Pandas suggests using symmetric_difference instead.

```py
cols_to_excl = ['Class']

df.loc[df[df.columns.symmetric_difference(cols_to_excl)].isnull().any(axis=1)]
```